# What's the proper way to render a single element of an array in Svelte?

Tags: arrays, typescript, svelte, conditional-rendering

I have an array of nodes, which in my case are objects that have some data, including an `id`. I only want to display the active node, which is found by comparing the node ID with the active node ID. I can do that successfully using this:

```
let active_node_id: string;
active_node_stream.subscribe((value) => (active_node_id = value));

...

{#each nodes as node (node.id)}
  {#if node.id === active_node_id}
    <Node {...node} />
  {/if}
{/each}
```

However, this pattern of looping through *all* the nodes only to display 1 node seems wrong. Is there a better way of doing this?

---

I thought to try to use Svelte's reactive declarations, so as to stop looping through the nodes once the active one was found, like so:

```
$: active_node_data = nodes.find(n => n.id === active_node_id)

...

<Node {...active_node_data} />
```

But this gives me the following error (I'm using TypeScript -- it seems to [work fine with JavaScript](https://svelte.dev/repl/36f24a99f6b54d9fb44f288b08399fa8?version=3.58.0) when I try to reproduce it):

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
  at $$self.$$.update
```

I'm not sure why this error occurs as the `active_node_id` should always match a node's ID... I have logged the node values and the `active_node_id` when this error happens and they do indeed match...

Regardless, this approach doesn't feel *significantly* better than the `each` with `if` approach. Is there a better way that's still Svelte-y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chatted with my acquaintance [yuanchuan](https://twitter.com/yuanchuan23) about this. He [recommended](https://www.sveltelab.dev/#code=N4IgdADgTgpgLnAljKUDGIBcoBmiA2MWoaA9gHZwyUDOxIA1ouQCZYg0BuM%2BV%2BAhgCMAtAFdEADn4gANCEGicOFFgDaARgBMAZhnqADDICcM7QBY96gOyWArHv3qZEi0ZtGJd0xduftmywA2Swt1awcnM1DDE3MvA3swwwNdA08DJwknMJsw7PVgjO8ZX1MAsML1UPCiqIdjYoqQ41z9RP10tstk-V1A3LCHEwMTN2LS-0aDS3yepzi66djq8qqHROmmiVb25IKHCziJgLMTM09zmUWYqfKOy1bUrqSvI78Ao3mV5qKmv%2BfHM0zBs7ukar11t0rhsNp1svd-l9jLprg04mFQQ8HE8NoYJE8nGMwq5hvoLIFOhtqvY3mVjEizME4kYUdE0dV8nCfmsEg45q8fO96XodHT0fo7u0uWEaYKxRYzCdKrCIg4wYVAQtDgF0YMMUFIXkoTLxkKtLpJrqPgNqariab5fF1NKEfsinFJloaeVNPYWfUvQ4ALoAXzDcgg-DQDH4AHMYGAAFY0Cj0PCEehkSjUOB0bCMZhsTAcbi8HhCMSSaRyBRKFSYDSipZTGKtUlI463bnwjWE4b7LX1ZaWaU89TtDazB2WhUXYKXRlXYeo4f6%2B28sKeIluzVyz1usetSJs1duzT5O4doXi-vwvatLmD5u6v396Igg0m2meps3YceLENwRfRDG-HVqkpT9NQ%2BMEdjVPlihXdkEN%2BZ1p3AkdDR3eY7n5TdEJPZC1x5QF8KA-Jh07XVIMROliOiTlDVI9RVxuQMkPFPC0IpO0tF4nouJiUl2nyWUSjNX8GmHQJbTI0jXV7BxlSudxWlbSxVkU%2B1gRaQCDyvR0jB8QxFwXec-AVQjpNktDfgUu19GUsxWjgpowOKIylyuYJbBRcyCKHIi%2BPXZjKg1ETmnc5ljO8kp538p8-y7EL8jCpj8gVD80kAiEN2mHSTTk%2BF1VVKLXBixdbHirzEqkqYVTskr3T3DDPNsSIfN0WwlSuCyrisqYaOw9CPJ8HrTli7rGjY30A1mgxQ3DDh0HoFhEFgNA4FIKAAE96H4CAIDAAALOAAFt8DTAgiHzLMqFoegmFYdguB4PgK3EKRZHkRRlCgNRAlAvpPCsEx%2BmcCwJBMCRDECWI7mqDVSU8QI7hkQGDig5G6Pubcej6JFUNA8k0bBnoGN0gxYdJhoMZGXjgjGSYjFJVwbXiUL0cJmodxOewquKSZnPRmmyaGBndP3dT6aKQJuZo5j%2B1WDKDQ9D5b2NYaXiaOWpmElCd3JO9eMglnVQKlimL2DVDm1FSRcC2IBga%2BSmvk1z9kXAwKaJEDTFaWmTNaH21IdzYbgxgCjSpkUcIQ7dGZsC2XeKqD4Q9%2BcspI1OjV9kzdkp-Yxl18UOUw1DbbDpK6b9vKzXHT9z3g2XCdr54G7XXHcibzszejzYtYH5S4lR-2nRdN306w6qo71Wum%2B0GwMeFmO66rwP7dn42tCcUfpmX4Osfgvf9EWkM5HwRBBFW9aYE27a9vzABZeBjtIFh1DAV6yyujNbooe6uZHqFheqWd6IhPrVh%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%2BcgX5wDfiwTQX8wE3VwNdTMACcx5lAE9IsJY3rlggVWb6tY-oAz2K%2BH47dNLry6UBJWyixwiPFVC0qdxiEjNRdochzcugAWFtGtxDCCnZVokmkoHCjmAt%2BIorBAifESylis8pEi46fGRPmzhVLSIluCnqSN5bZkbIVcS3R7LcXTIHiY7KhyehAriUkjJdj-gOKCbYQwnYgLcOnbGl5q9mIVPVQaJmuEI2gS2czVmgT0nujuP2TRmMhbjsLXI4WrTJigyWTITJ2Sr2jq6doHpUrC6LNJaMAY3CCWwSYp0GI4yNV9PaH%2BpRzzIVuJNM0kdY7uniU5ee-4BTlVVpJWBrdNhDFxxmXcnDTQnkCW-fKyDhcTh2y5eh75aqyX7IbeHJDHKchQm7e3KczMgNARAwx6VEHgn-sfbB1V8GCOSXfU20cIj6bbgAwR8OFFJ1UcfQhylSHgUSgjXbGDwFUr%2BJVWupT8Il18vEw3P5PoAXSa00ulFams0SxgxZkzMLGPvNXZKjTjb7N0XmiK05wLs6gvZi8G5UH9SIdDYFvz2nSkcaJVx65dwCRbuI0XJOZHHnuEowp-qqHPl0Z5X28lAXbPBapaFv4YLUvzNwwxqLfEva3MM882j%2BT6OkoLr569S64sHzpW%2BLCwbdXJFZX27hnWBlMJ%2BWJ9zAryMhPaEhsVaT3M3ME0vBRugZuKuw95-kS3csBe1UvZlop9XtENcakAprzXaCte63%2BNqQB3UdcA56xZv7gMrF9Gsv16yqHgQGkKyCQ1Nso6WlRUaNuSpufGiVibk05tTVQp98P%2BTOcGTm4aebEP9fkSKPhunVYePJ0d6t%2BHOXSOY0F4nWhSf90Rh29RHzOMYbKzWozOVOieEJwzxJd7cFToCRK2dByzQGv8TbFdC3JVfh3adrbu7WGU77mSI9hH4T%2Bbs-rqr2vcXLpPfK5LKoJl2QhX7FXqx9Zo-rhse3RdD2I8DfkVI4JPE7nSLUid%2BqkO3uSY%2B59LTX3xcsZ%2Brt5vuvDIl0qzLiyac3PSyRxPulXPGcV1ZmjaGuuld%2BRS8xSHEHe8xQes3mNTcDq4qi2xTnysxabYll4nO1cp4lid8D2WqeoTWbn4r%2Be5sMd65Jyreuik6aFhc2jWvahy%2B3Gs9SbeC9AXK9ZkU4%2BDesZqwecLhazaz4pq11Pntl8x9X55ovRO7PCon2zwzqvbdosrfHvvHm4Vkf05iuyqL8UOZ-3kmxT2Rp3xVrTz1mx2W5z6yF0N0XRaRy27yY3%2BQj3vzkUPzQzn3oWUlmQ6wgIO17V%2BTtk3RIyTmv1gNYzi2333Aplq332t223pyLVmhuXRlpRNHpVGwNHG031MCmyKxX2H0wzf0IJIKyy1VQMMUMAzVVSfyQNlVFH2x7Xmzc0lS70ax-HO3Xj1Vch0y9DuwADl34Exfs3t0w3sPsHp8wXVQF3UBBPUAdoFfU4F-VB8GViIUEaZi1mc21WcblZMv1TtEMhsOCRs8oxtmVYYyM159wf8m40dd4GQ1kwc54Ns1gF1fxGDFxS9m5fCJCR4TlAV4EplJ950JIngsicUJt7AQi%2BJUEuliiw4lg2xVQMiKjlsk5KhpZHNi0aj2C6jCjRVSdR4ci8cVY2iGtSDYpRjXRsFZpaiSj6gQi24VQeDQdG4c5AR6im1EVMIUCb84CVinRMQQkpccZPd3C-Ym979O4txMDIgUjvctIh4UMK8iYWF7Rrjt95NwtblhlOw51epGVFEhYBdNNvi%2BI846E48IQASTIwQfR51wTDd9x7da4Ak4SgTLg1xFEviUSEYHJ2gnhWdOwIkolgSkTJDDcAJZ9HhuxzkEIF00IGl1NkjB8c48ivM2UzlsSdNeSTgLhyDKDVtQ0%2BJ9iKDQ1HMWTCN-ihRLg8Szslj%2Bi4jNjd5NAz4looBSBRAqAnUQA1oNotpdp6AABqSMeML%2BFAbgKAJMPU8w%2B1bMKw51EBH7a1ew-7KBH1YHbwxlPInBdkzWcvIRQYKE5PD5QqeIpYVFZ5Dff-CrQKEFOg7kCFSSUYXvddV4mCHKKUBCGQ9zHiU7GM3XYYWaQnUsgtHoFvKM7lNtCFNYPGBCTPHKM4MfKk93MLZM1TS3LXVrYM-IFWZ5evbshUSoNmY0dE%2BEFJZA2JXndjemGAiQljNjHmC5ErWszlXjAEfjPMyVAspAos%2BMg4lNR-JHDMuc%2ByMM4Uf0BUt3FnBA48ynXkS8%2BU1FJ8qZIJMkrEsElpFEHEac3go80U2gxhIdT2SoKs9oBUCbLffE1jRjBdLoVEaguA5ozBQEKifsbo9saEdXIWGJSEJC2CuzGYtIlqYwUc9JNNUCQoJsesgYL-ededLqFEBRfvMUGii4o3BFEoJikoFiiQrkji5oBsmOZ5QE3yPipjdiQkDUNAw1JjG8%2BSo8xMvfTsmg6tc8kqMso1MMc%2BEAM0uMEw61V7B0wBPUmw10uwj6L1QHGBP1YbQNCHVBNE8NO8-0%2BvWZb2KtCaW8scScsUVHYCP0DHDyzmLy%2BPCJHA4fPHRSAnZEnGaHVtbBVRJ9MXOXePQE3yhxFHZDNHYK%2B2UKwzcKmNQEnHaK%2Byd0NheKjFTBJKste9NKqvEqgjPQvy8WMhXKoKypAqxq4q42dqGFRhCeFhOK4vbCpnX05KuTAzR8m3JAxSh8-0tfHnUEpg5S1q%2BiwfWbbjNLCWKwdog88UuS9spMlRIJIcjVLy3s3I-soEaQ1SbxBhMc4pLPKcjfEXSY8QwIPydM8Rb6jzUcfGR6oU2LVbWolI9w1tTw4vSOXjA8SoHatXUoTXU2UkHbXgw6qZNUhKgxLG84vag68rTQyHQFCQLKOakajnC-YfGqtdNgzeOGtKfuamGG%2B6iWPqxs181Q6FBQ9owsrorDM8lgqmmsqAvZXmvZQMRJVBMVXqufEqusrPHm3bT6xZBhJWjS4WyvNcsW5aiW5aqW8dGWtmzy%2BW-qpTDW9-fWimqY9WwW8RQ27WofXWxja2guR2nVdU3SuQWMfAUgQQfgfAMANAGgO0u1f%2BR0oBawl0t1Msd0yBb1IHWBVQUoFRW6pa1MnC5OBwJOfK2knCryzE%2BUnwDhM4NkwqfQXO7q-OnSAagqeWnMgE0urOvxAwKumkzAquiaBC2Se4GMi4PTPwJOPTM4ckxeBS5unSbOtunCju4rSunC8S6XXui4eEwrVa8erzT8y4TeoUsugujuBenSOezXKuganujmVenioE2wSyOkW%2BkoHUYe%2B%2BmwAWXepg-e6eo%2BvOzuxegIC%2Biuq%2B0qgXO%2ByYKaKaTeu2WwV%2B%2BYMgj%2Blujmduu4%2Bes%2BrqZey%2Bx9YBkoUB-%2BteyB%2B%2BhKOBxDT%2B1u7%2Bj4ltTOLyABw%2Bq%2BhcQeseLethWBiewKKe0hqu2iCapoWusonGFe9TAelpIe9e3BkoGkIhye8uw%2BjhrWChxes4m5fhsS%2BdAUkRuKBhqB-%2Bp%2Blh5sNhxBg%2B9KoA82NZZxPhjBmMthVkFpUeoE-BsB5ihhvehBiumRwx-y2ofmXhxR8xxix%2BrEqBpkZ%2BsBrRxx%2BBvRlxgxqvIxjxkoBRgkwBzBteqaRhr8jR%2B%2BnwZhhckh-R%2Bu-hSFKPHUEwB9XHMccMxhGkM4PTP0ETW44x%2BISMwA-yrzQIChLCHoahB6s2fEWOJ0ZFIp4zF4rk6GVPXKOeOOMmp9C0SpukCQfhLeUFY8DJEsibeEU-EyO2CZ2eTapMpCMGB6-JwuWg4CQRjqqwXY%2B0bdZwPbbZhuPNIZ9GMEBxAuSYbpkS256Z05y8XIgI3kDAjJUcOxO54ghBG5qRiKcHM5Yh5x6Rgu1qp42FjWMTDCp9c5ui1TZm2hIFnGRFtzRhEWoobSsarHHpo60YZB0%2B49Nquc%2BFWexF2Y5oJk5B7SfOA%2B9oJB7WshuupxkisnRlw51k1lnOyJn07hkxnRtiKU34v8l4UkucMRyS3-eB5c%2BF3JymHorcnpvllkmMsFoV1VjF7h7l89TXFVx4m6hl%2BuJltYHVwVmei2NxtCh4ryBcu-feaIcao4y51zU8szXiW0Y%2Bul0iwVzXI57ChC6pPV1s5sVOqlttOTTO7JiJ4%2B8ltGrO0x7xhJ-utRneoJk4Gx9%2BqFxNmF5Njls%2Brx%2BJmhgR7N4RlJt%2BiRx2aFtl2elNvV-mOJpqnMrNremtkevxgt5uotptktmu-mf%2B9BzNte7ttJsB3x-tht8J4tn%2BlBxetBsxid-xoR6dkJnN8VuqBdodxpknA0Ke9Nitztyd%2Bhux-%2BpOGt7lxt1t8h62Re8tjt%2BCLty93N9RndrJhofdh9zhuR2u9t4q89jdjez9h%2BiSud5sV1v8YlneQ8pKHlu87OkNrFVo6XCNmeqF2DqSPDGzBt5DvIrV9mG1r%2B1xqJ9x%2BhNt3dks1bZsMYGNoadlLWY3BNgMsYi1tdyt5R7B%2BVlJyJLd%2BVqD%2BtmDuLYVDU722OqgYOigPAWMW0kyiOsyr7V1Uw%2BOmypw70gEVyv0lKqEgrThtYLKhNAK9GGyYazhxyLwYWAzmpweTKQuS6wYUaljIPCdQxVnBDzuKNnTyastZ5PNGSceBySeJSGzlyaedXZpRccGA1vQgEVILW1pAPUYgeIMjj8OSffC6ZTOmevKApgCpKW9fDtVvJYNCuWegYZz0zcc33JTDYezvJ9tJXJ0Kjlq73IaEhcOcal4%2BDYF8FwhYqpm1tfmDHfVDOQa7NCq7AyzDHVeEM-sNZfZm2qGv1qrvSBGwpMnDZfwrCTFVrPdpOUr-as5H8dOurG5TrrCbrnoXrp92m251YAZuTEC305rrz%2BSOslWc7iNUriuoqn3Byb7%2BrS5wqYKXRNEjBM2K7zWLrtXGWZiJ9rzcH53RmV3ZrjVfcB1jZMQir5iEc%2Bd47mZkZlqrzg8OpFDEroVgrqb%2BjGK82DULiebicwfZbsrtTIz20Xyn709MnU3PKSs-nyVmsxGvpNIrH8M1b-H5KtZWStMuz3054sixXjw9bg8sT%2Bj8s4vEVuq2HL9OyMp0CkRNLoXoCGRYMKTzgRAGTrMeTxT-Me05Tz7aO77aTj1D0xOuyhsMNfz-XlA2I%2BnmbqeWn4mkz5HMz4L8Hyz1jpySL2nleJhQ91z85novX9tAPndQ3tp1UOL9ctjRLxU8PueHKuSZPqqnX5tHwqag3%2BSI33I6avCBLmE3eAYTxZv9JGDPLiHzc6V9LzM4UaP0Lj4hehP8rf0FlNZcgjUoAA) using a `Map` paired with an `if` for instances like this, which feels a lot nicer.

First you need to build a map (I did it where my nodes data was):

```
export const node_map = build_data_map(nodes);

function build_data_map(nodes: node[]) {
  const map = new Map<string, node>();
  for (const node of nodes) {
    map.set(node.id, node);
  }
  return map;
}
```

Then you can import that map and use it to find the currently active node:

```
let active_node_id: string;
active_node_stream.subscribe((value) => (active_node_id = value));

$: active_node_data = node_map.get(active_node_id);

...

{#if active_node_data}
  <Node {...active_node_data} />
{/if}
```

So using Svelte's reactivity is the way to go, but there are nicer ways to do it like using a map.

However, the approach provided above prevents transitions when the active node is changed from occurring (in my case I am hiding non-active ones). This is because the above approach uses a single instance of a node, only switching out the data, as opposed to truly transitioning an element in or out. As a result, I stuck with the original approach I had, using the `each` with `if`.

---

Side note: It turns out the `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')` error was coming from inside of my `Node` component when a property was not being passed in for certain nodes. It was caused by these lines:

```
export let options: answer_obj[] = [];
$: is_choice = options.length !== 0;
```

I expected options to always have a length (at least be 0) and not be `undefined` sometimes. `$: is_choice = options?.length !== 0;` also threw the error, which is surprising. But `$: is_choice = options ? options.length !== 0 : false;` worked without error. I don't understand why the optional chaining method didn't work (maybe it's an issue with the compiler?) nor do I why this was not an issue with the `each` approach...

Answer (score 0):

I think the reactive assignment is indeed the **Svelte-y** way of doing this sort of tasks.

The problem in your code and why typescript is unhappy with it, is because the `find` could return undefined if the node were not found.

> MDN docs -> find: Returns the value of the first element in the array where predicate is true, and **undefined** otherwise.

so just provide a default value in case it is undefined, something like this would do the trick:

```js
$: active_node_data = nodes.find(n => n.id === active_node_id) ?? {id: "default"}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know why it might return `undefined` if the active node ID is always set to an ID of a node? Is there a part of the Svelte lifecycle where it can be "in between" the old and new value or something along those lines?

Comment: no not really, I tried your code and it never returned undefined... if you have another code that produces the undefined I would be happy to check it out.